# Volume of complex submanifolds

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Let $X$ be a projective algebraic manifold and let $w$ be any Kahler metric on $X$. Then the volume of any complex submanifold of $X$ w.r.t $w$ is bounded below by a uniform positive constant. 
My question is: is this true for certain noncompact complex manifolds? for example, denote by $B$ the unit ball in $\mathbb C^n$ and let $K$ be a compact subset of $B$. Then is there a positive constant $C$ such that any complex submanifold of $B$ that has nonempty intersection with K has volume bigger than $C$, say with respect to the standard flat metric?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I guess you want your complex submanifolds to also be closed subsets? By definition, every open subset of a complex submanifold is also a complex submanifold.

Comment: Yes, I mean closed complex submanifolds. Thanks for your clarification.

Comment: This is a consequence of the lower bound for volumes of intersection of analytic sets with ball of fixed radius with center on the analytic set.See for example page 190 of Chirka Complex Analytic Sets

Comment: Mohan: That's right. Thank you very much for telling me this reference!